# Pandas/Openpyxl - Save Current Date into xlsx Filename

Tags: pandas, openpyxl, python-3.10

Trying to save an xlsx file and include the current date in the file name during the process. Currently, I'm using the below code but I receive the error `invalid format string` - uncertain what format I can use to accomplish this.

I saw this method recommended in another thread but it doesn't work for me. I've tried several other solutions as well but nothing seems to work. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import datetime, date
import os
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

file = glob(
    'C:\\Users\\all*.xlsx')[0]

wb1 = load_workbook(file)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

for row in ws1['A2':'D5']:
    for cell in row:
        cell.value = None

wb1.save('file1'+now.strftime("%Y%m%d%")+'.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the `save` command where you have an extra `%` in the end. Also, just `now` is not sufficient, it needs the `()`. For the code above, think it also needs the `datetime.` to be added. So, change the last line from....

```
wb1.save('file1'+now.strftime("%Y%m%d%")+'.xlsx')
```

to

```
wb1.save('file1'+datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")+'.xlsx')
```